# Simple Stats Question I Think

Tags: statistics

I am probably overthinking this but I am having difficulty on a monday morning reading my stats book from undergrad.  I have two cohorts in a single total population.  Cohort B regularly attends the dentist and Cohort A never does.  I suspect doing to the dentist, or the underlying psychology of taking care of oneself evidenced by dental care, is related to attending an annual physical at your doctor's.  In Cohort A 70 people got their physical out of 4000.  In Cohort B, 4000 got their physical out of 40000.

Cohort A ("Never Been to the Dentist Group"):  70/1000
Cohort B ("Regularly Goes to the Dentist Group"):  4000/40000

I assume this is a two proportion t test which I calculate to succeed at both one and two tails.

Just hoping for some support from the interwebs because I don't usually need to go back to my statistics work but this is important.  (The actual analysis, not this dentist example :))

Comment: There is a statistics stack exchange. https://stats.stackexchange.com/ I have voted to close and to move the topic there automatically.

Comment: Oh whoops!  thank you much!

Comment: "In Cohort A 70 people got their physical out of 4000" then "Cohort A ("Never Been to the Dentist Group"): 70/1000"